# Is there a final decision on whether ISKCON texts are quotable as scripture at this site?

Tags: discussion

I am not just talking about translations - also about their theological statements pertaining to Hindu deities.

Comment: I don't understand why don't you the same for Ramakrishna Mission? Ramakrishna Mission has itself declared legally to be non-Hindu organisation. See https://www.indiatoday.in/magazine/religion/story/19860215-ramkrishna-missions-non-hindu-claim-causes-dismay-among-many-of-its-followers-800581-1986-02-15

Comment: They should be allowed. After all, they belong to Gaudiya Vaishnavism.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Do you know why they did so? "Whatever legal brains have done is for lawyers to say" - RK Mission General Secretary, Swami Atmashtananda. The RK Mission's explanation has been all along that it has taken this step to save its schools, and that the court statements are simply part of the necessary legal maneuvers.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria I don't think so. https://media.belurmath.org/christmas-eve-2018-3724

Comment: @Ambi They consider Jesus as Yogi which is why they consider Christmas Eve as a sacred day.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria You will of course understand if I don't subscribe to such ideas. We can't condemn one and embrace another when both are to be looked at via the same lens.

Comment: @Ambi There is not much I can do when you think respecting other religions or people from other religion is wrong or non-Hindu. Sri Ramakrishna warned against dogmatism, everyone thinks their watch alone shows the correct time.

Comment: @Chinmaysarupria I didn't ask you to. Like so many people here who consider themselves too perceptive, please stop assuming things about me and what I think. Esp funny when I am seen as harboring hatred while the real hatred spewing is cajoled, encouraged even. Its odd that for all the outraging on respect and other high flying words, even within here, people don't blink twice before demonizing other siddhanta followers out of their own bias. The even more odd thing is the outrage is always selective!

Comment: @Ambi You are mixing up topics here. That meta post which you are hinting at has got nothing to do with this post.

Comment: Christmas is a huge, secular festival for Hindus everywhere.  There is nothing Christian in how Hindus celebrate Christmas and is purely inclusive.  Contrast this with the so called Chinna Jeeyar who insists that any portraits of Siva in any hall he is going to give a talk in be covered up before the talk.

Comment: If you are not talking about scriptures then which texts are you talking about? the books that were composed by their scholars? @SK

Answer (score -5):

They have stated many times (including Prabhupada) that they are not Hindu.

Now I am citing this post from here

[What is the current status of Gaudiya Math?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/what-is-the-current-status-of-gaudiya-math)

> Do they regard ISKCON as a part of their math?
>
> No, definitely not. They are absolutely different and separate organisations. ISKCON is one of the many break away factions of the Gaudiya Math. I don't have any sources to quote acharyas of Gaudiya Math saying they don't consider ISKCON as a part of their organisation but I can quote some old letters of Prabhupada where he slams the Gaudiya Mission:

So the organization lineally descended from the Gaudiya tradition has separated from ISKCON and ISKCON has stated many times that they are not Hindu.

They now have as much in common with Hinduism as Christianity has in common with Judaism.  They share a small subset of Hindu scripture (which they freely edit) but they also have new scripture not in common with Hinduism - such as Vedic yagnas dedicated to Krishna.

Comment: "They have stated many times (including Prabhupada) that they are not Hindu." - Where does Prabhupada say this?